# project spherical coordinates into cube python

Tags: python, map-projections

Given a sphere radius of 1 and center at (0,0,0,), I have a list of xyz points in spherical coordinates of the form:

```
[-0.31828382 -0.6678262   0.67283251] # between -1 and 1
```

what would be the way to get their projected coordinates on a containing cube of same size?

Comment: I don't see how the added code enhances the question.  The method of generating the points doesn't affect the mathematical transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to project this vector until one of the components first intercepts the cube boundary.  Since your boundaries are -1 and +1, this is simple.

The component with the largest magnitude is the third one, 0.672...
Divide each component by that magnitude, and you have your interception point:

```
[-0.31828382, -0.6678262, 0.67283251]
[-0.47305060, -0.9925594, 1.0]
```

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I don't understand the problem; [x, y, z] coordinates *are* Cartesian.